# Loading a web map from ArcGIS Portal on-premise

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, arcgis-portal

In my application, I have a few navigation tabs.  Each tab loads a web map from Portal for ArcGIS on-premise.

When each tab is clicked, it asks for the Portal credentials in order to load the maps.

I want end users to log in once on the main page and be able to access the maps without logging in over and over again.  Are there any ways do so or other alternative ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Named User Login](https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/signing-in-arcgis-online-users/) guide in the documentation.

You should register your app in the portal and use the [IdentityManager class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-IdentityManager.html) to handle their authentication. This should prevent the subsequent logins.

Comment: The app is not created using any ArcGIS ready-made templates or using ArcGIS webappbuilder. Can I still register the app in the portal?

Comment: Yes, you can still register it. The first step is to add a new item (Web Application) which just creates an item within the portal. Then on the item details page, hit the register button to generate the `appId`. Be sure to set the redirect URI to the location your app will be hosted.

Comment: Thank you so much Evan. I am going to apply your suggestion.

Comment: This is called Application Authentication. This video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_csHP33lVY8

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to change the Sharing properties of the WebMap to Share with my Portal.

Comment: Try the "Everyone" sharing option, pretty sure the users would still have to log into the Portal, but then wouldn't have to log in anymore.

Comment: @Maksim Sharing with "everyone" may be undesirable. You're basically removing the security layer instead of managing it.